# Medalha: Ganhou mas não levou

Tags: bug, status-pronto, medalhas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não se se foi algum `bug` na plataforma mas havia ganhado essas medalhas, fiquei com 6 de ouro, hoje elas sumiram.

Comment: Não da pra ver as imagens aqui, mas se for relacionadas a sinalizações, isso foi um bug do sistema, já corrigido pelo pessoal da SE e as medalhas dadas indevidamente foram todas removidas, conforme pode ser visto [neste post do metão](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280028/310559)

Comment: Pelo visto foi isso mesmo @diegofm